# Bind value to xslt variable with choose-when-otherwise

Tags: c#, xslt

I am using xslt to transform xml to xml with c#. Below is an extract from the xslt where variables assignment is being shown.

```
<xsl:variable name="testvar">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$condition">
     <xsl:value-of select="myUtils:Method1($var1,$var2)" /> 
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="myUtils:Method2($var1,$var2)" /> <!--Method1 and Method 2 are written in c# code.-->
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

The above assignment is different from the below assignment:

```
<xsl:variable name="testvar" select="myUtils:Method1($var1,$var2)"/>
```

Another variable depends on the above variable as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="testvar2" select="$testvar/node()[1]/node()[1]/node()[1]/node()[1]"/>
```

This variable is assigned the expected value when `$testvar` is assigned in the second way.

The return type of both `Method1` and `Method2` is `XmlDocument`. I think there is something wrong with `<xsl:value-of>`. What is the correct way of assigning this variable?

**UPDATE**
I have solved the issue by the following code:

```
<xsl:variable name="testvar"><xsl:copy-of select="myUtils:Method1($var1,$var2)"/></variable>
```

For the second variable I have used the below code:

```
<xsl:variable name="testvar2" select="msxsl:node-set($testvar)/node()[1]/node()[1]/node()[1]/node()[1]"/>
```

Please refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz88kef0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your **Method1** functions returns node-set, as opposed to simple text/number value. In this this case the issue is probably because **xsl:value-of** gets the "value" of a node, not the actual node itself.

Try using **xsl:copy-of** instead

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="myUtils:Method1($var1,$var2)" />
```

Comment: +1. I have just did that, and as for the second variable, I have used msxsl:node-set($testvar) to solve the problem.